# $f$ is continuous on int $\operatorname{dom} f$ if and only if int epi $f \neq \varnothing$.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $\mathcal{X}$ be a real Hausdorff locally convex topological vector space and let $f: \mathcal{X} \rightarrow \, {]}{-}\infty,+\infty]$ be convex. What we want to do is showing that $f$ is continuous on int $\operatorname{dom} f$ if and only if int epi $f \neq \varnothing$, where
$$\operatorname{dom} f := \{ x \in \mathcal{X} : f(x) < \infty\}, \qquad \operatorname{epi} f := \{ (x, \xi) \in \mathcal{X} \times \mathbb{R} : f(x) \leq \xi\}.$$

{The following is what I have tried}:

For the necessity: If $\operatorname{int} (\operatorname{epi} f) = \varnothing$, then
\begin{equation*}
    \overline{\mathcal{X} \times \mathbb{R} \, \setminus \, \operatorname{epi} f} = \mathcal{X} \times \mathbb{R} \, \setminus \, \operatorname{int} \operatorname{epi} f = \mathcal{X} \times \mathbb{R}.
\end{equation*}
Take any net $\{ (x_a, \xi_a) \}_{a \in A} \in \operatorname{epi} f \subset \mathcal{X} \times \mathbb{R}$ such that $ (x_a, \xi_a)  \rightarrow (x, \xi)$, then the closeness of $\mathcal{X} \times \mathbb{R} = \overline{\mathcal{X} \times \mathbb{R} \, \setminus \, \operatorname{epi} f} $ give that
\begin{equation*}
    (x, \xi) \in \overline{\mathcal{X} \times \mathbb{R} \, \setminus \, \operatorname{epi} f}
\end{equation*}
The continuity of $f$ will give that $(x, \xi) \notin \mathcal{X} \times \mathbb{R} \, \setminus \, \operatorname{epi} f$, then $(x, \xi)$ must lie in the boundary of $\mathcal{X} \times \mathbb{R} \, \setminus \, \operatorname{epi} f$. But I am stuck here. And I also do not know how to deal with the sufficiency. Indeed, I do not know how to use the locally convex condition and $f$ is convex (I only know that $f$ is convex will give $\operatorname{epi} (f)$ is convex).

Could anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you define epi $f$?

Comment: @ajr Thanks for comments. I have added the definition.

Comment: Do you mean by $\mathcal{X} \times \mathbb{R} \, / \, \operatorname{epi} f$ the complement $\mathcal X \times \mathbb R \setminus \operatorname{epi} f$?  If so, then your slash should be a backslash, typeset as a math operator as `\setminus`.  Also, do you mean $x \in \operatorname{dom} f$ to require only that $f(x) < +\infty$, or also that $f(x) > -\infty$?  Finally, what does convexity require of the values of $f$ on a segment joining a point of $f^{-1}(-\infty)$ to a point of $f^{-1}(+\infty)$?

Comment: @LSpice Thanks for your correction. Now I confirm that the value of $f(\mathcal{X}) \subset \, ] - \infty, + \infty]$.